# Laravel Algolia multiple cloumn search

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

How can I search in two column in my mysql table  example : I want search product name and with sku
I found some function but I cant entegreted , now only search with product name.
public function search(Builder $builder)
{
$result = [];

```
        $query = DB::table($builder->model->searchTable());

        $columns = implode(',', $builder->model->searchColumns());

          $query->whereRaw("MATCH ({$columns}) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $this->getSearchKeyword($builder));

        if ($builder->callback) {
            $query = call_user_func($builder->callback, $query, $this);
        }

        $result['count'] = $query->count();

        if (property_exists($builder, 'orders') && ! empty($builder->orders)) {
            foreach ($builder->orders as $order) {
                $query->orderBy($order['column'], $order['direction']);
            }
        }

        if ($builder->limit) {
            $query = $query->take($builder->limit);
        }

        if (property_exists($builder, 'offset') && $builder->offset) {
            $query = $query->skip($builder->offset);
        }

        $result['results'] = $query->pluck($builder->model->searchKey());

        return $result;
    }
        private function getProducts(Product $model)
    {
        return $model->search(request('query'))
            ->query()
            ->limit(10)
            ->withName()
            ->withBaseImage()
            ->withPrice()
            ->addSelect([
                'products.id',
                'products.slug',
                'products.in_stock',
                'products.manage_stock',
                'products.qty',
                'products.sku',
            ])
            ->with(['files', 'categories' => function ($query) {
                $query->limit(5);
            }])
            ->when(request()->filled('category'), $this->categoryQuery())
            ->get();
         }
```